# Flash AS3 making it so whenever a button is clicked on screen is like pressing a specific keyboard key

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hello I am working on a game in flash, in the mobile version of this app I am trying to make it so in a mousedown event on a button it will be equal to the Left, Right keycodes etc. being active?

Is there a way in AS3 for a keyboard key to be activated by other means such as mouse clicks?

```
leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, leftKeyPress)
function leftKeyPress(e:MouseEvent){
    // Left Key is pressed
        Keyboard.LEFT;
        trace("trace statement");
}
```

This code doesent seem to work

EDIT: also this is important this class and the class that uses the keyboard(The player) are in two seperate classes, so Im trying to make it so that when this is click it is recognized as a key press on a keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but It is all wrong. You can't trigger keyboard events like that. That is the way of capturing events. And your function is also a MouseEvent. Should be keyboard event. I Opened Flash after one year. Anyway. AFAI understand you are trying to disable keyboard until mouse click somewhere.

```
leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, leftKeyPress);
var keyEnabled:Boolean = false;
function leftKeyPress(e:MouseEvent){
    keyEnabled = true;
}

key.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);

function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(keyPressed){
        //do whatever here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually dispatch a keyboard event; however, is not the best design pattern:

```
dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,
                                true,
                                false,
                                Keyboard.LEFT,
                                Keyboard.LEFT));
```

It would be better to establish two handlers:

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveKeyHandler);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveMouseHandler);
```

From each handler, call a function that abstracts movement function from the handlers:

```
protected function moveKeyHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    /* switch statement for key */
    moveLeft();
}

protected function moveMouseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    /* switch statement for button target */
    moveLeft();
}

protected function moveLeft():void
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for always answering everyones as3 Jason! I forgot to mention that the class this button is in and the class that uses the keyboard (the player) are two different classes which is why im trying to find a way so that flash thinks that the left key has been press so players on mobile devices can use button inputs. so it isnt  a matter of making a mouseclick do the same thing as a keyboard press. Thank you very much for answering so many questions!